# Can't run different vb.net applications based on the same original app

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a desktop Windows Forms application I built.

As we try out improvements to the program, I make the changes on a test version of the application, which connects to a test copy of the Microsoft SQL database on the back end.

Basically, to start out, I just copied the program to a different directory, re-named the assembly, created a different PublicTokenKey and used that.

The problem is when I try to run a the test copy and the live copy at the same time.  It pretty clearly thinks they are the same program (when I click on the second one, the "busy" circle simple turns for a second, then the already-opened icon in the taksbar gets highlighted), even though they show up in the Task Manager as differently named applications.

What do I need to tweak in Visual Studio so Windows 10 will recognize them as different, separate programs?

Comment: What I usually do is copy the whole folder containing all those required files without changing anything. Then I add "test" at the end of the folder name. In this way, you can open both the programs independently of each other.

Comment: @SubazSarma - that's what I did, originally. However, unchecking the "run as single instance" box took care of the issue.